# What exactly is javascript Audio() and how does it work? How is it different from <audio>?

Tags: javascript, dom, audio

I have been wondering how javascript's `new Audio()` works. From Mozilla, it says that it's a dom audio object. What would the difference between this and the `<audio>` in html, or are they the same? From what I can tell, they are the same, because the return value of `new Audio()` in the browser console is `<audio></audio>`.

However, where is it inserted? Where is the `Audio()` in the html document, because even though I can play it with `Audio.prototype.play`, it still doesn't appear in the DOM?

Comment: They are the same. Just like you can create other HTML elements inside Javascript, you can also create Audio elements. The only difference is that if you create it in Javascript, you have to manually attach it to your DOM for users to be able to see it. Before you attach it, it only exists within the user's RAM

Comment: So the play() method only plays it on the user's RAM? It doesn't go into the dom?

Comment: Ye. Just like the documentation says: _"the audio will keep playing and the object will remain in memory until playback ends"_. This is about the garbage collection part, but the idea is the same. It'll just play in the user's RAM.

Comment: Since javascript is on client side. Ah, makes sense.